# How to check whether server is still connected to client or not in Java?

Tags: java, sockets

I want to check whether server is still connected to the client or not before reading from stream. How to do that in java? My current code is as below.Will this check only for client socket?

```
public void receiveResultFromServer() {
    try {
        while(!clientSocket.isClosed()) {
            try{
                Object obj = inStream.readObject();
                if (obj instanceof Command) {
                    ConnectionManager.parseCommand((Command) obj);
                } else if (obj instanceof CommandExecResult) {
                    ConnectionManager.parseCommandExecutionResult((CommandExecResult) obj);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: If it's not, you get an `IOException`. Also, please use formatting.

Comment: @immbis Not necessarily. A read doesn't do anything to the network, it just waits. Unless there is a read timeout or there have been writes which fail, a read can block forever.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing connectivity just before reading streams is not good. Instead design a heartbeat mechanism.

Algorithm :

a) design two commands using enum "SEND_BEAT" and "RECEIVE_BEAT" on both client and server.

b) Now as soon as your server starts, start a thread that sends a signal **from server to client(HandShake Protocol)** using the the commands and client will respond back to the signal to the server.

c) this sending signal job can be scheduled at regular interval of time, using Java Timer and TimerTask classes available for e.g.

```
  scheduleAtFixedRate(new RunTimer(), 5000, 1000);
```

d) on the basis of response, maintain the status of client on the server.

e) Now you can use status for checking the connectivity between the client and server.

f) In fact, you can even design a re-connect mechanism which will try for certain number of times before final update.

h) Also you need to maintain the state as checkpoint as per your need.

hopefully above algo fulfills your demand.

Answer (score 0):

If the peer has disconnected, your code will throw am `EOFException`. If there has been a network failure it might block forever, so you might want to consider using a read timeout, which would throw a `SocketTimeoutException`.